# how can i flip or rotate a diagram picture generate in Word with m2doc service

Tags: m2doc

When I create a diagram in with sirius. m2doc is able to generate the image in the Word document. my problem is that it is not possible to rotate this too large image in portrait mode. I have a class that implement MImage and a service. How can I get it from an ImageServices. my link help: http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/2.0.2/m2doc_service_imageservices.html

I tried to transform the image using imageData by "org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData". Is not working

```
public MImage rotate(MImage image) {
    java.lang.System.out.println("START TRANSFORMATION  " + image);
    SbocsImage sbocsImage = null;

    try {
        imgSizer = new ImageResizer( new ImageData(image.getInputStream()) );
        sbocsImage = new SbocsImage( imgSizer.rotateImage(SWT.RIGHT), image);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    java.lang.System.out.println("END CLOSE TRANSFORMATION  " + image);
    return image;
}
```

image is not rotate.

Answer (score 1):

On the master branch there is a new implementation of MImage that use a BufferedImage. It is used in the [resize() service](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/b209ded301936b9b73094b132943e054c0d1515f/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/services/ImageServices.java#L235).

You can have a look at [issue 344](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/344) and the corresponding [commit](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/commit/b209ded301936b9b73094b132943e054c0d1515f) for more context.

Can you open an [issue](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues) to create the rotate service ?